# lang/expect: the expect fails every few runs of the kvm

Tags: expect

I'm using [expect](http://ports.su/lang/expect) to control `kvm` / `qemu`, and I'm having an issue that re-running the very same script produces different results, with sometimes the code failing to work as expected, even though the output I see from within `kvm` is exactly the same between the runs (using `-display curses` of `kvm`).  I've tried passing `-d` to `expect`, and it appears that, (1), the buffer that expect is working with never gets cleared of the old stuff (e.g., stuff that preceded the stuff that the prior `expect "…"` was supposed to have matched), and, (2), the spaces don't really work as spaces.

Below is an example of "login: " showing up in the terminal, but never matching the `expect "login: "`, I expect it has something to do with colour, but I'm not too sure what's the best way to turn it off from `kvm`:

`DragonFly/x86_64 (Amnesiac) (ttyv0)\u001b[38;74H\u001b[28X\u001b[39dlogin:\u001b[74G\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49m\u001b[37m\u001b[40m\u001b[15;36r\u001b[36;1H\u001b[7S\u001b[1;54r\u001b[31;74H\u001b[37m\u001b[40mFri Feb 16 05:29:19 UTC 2018\u001b[32;74HWelcome to DragonFly!\u001b[34;74HTo start the installer, login as 'installer'.  To just get a shell prompt,\u001b[35;74Hlogin as 'root'.\u001b[39;81H\u001b[30m\u001b[47m \u001b[39;74H\u001b(B\u001b[m\u001b[39;49m\u001b[37m\u001b[40m" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "login: "? no`

Comment: Post your script.

Comment: What you're seeing is a coloured (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)) output sent by whatever [`getty`-class process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getty_(Unix)) your host system has. Why exactly does it use the control codes is beyond me; this may (or may not) be judged based on the terminal type your client sets (`xterm` typically sets "xterm" unless overridden or it's a 256-color variant of `xterm` etc). I'd try to work from there *or* modify the `expect` script to ignore these codes.

Comment: @kostix, yes, I realise it's the colour codes; it all shows up "properly" without any codes, the above snippet is from running `expect` with the `-d` option, hence, you can see all these codes from the debug output of expect itself.  I've tried `set env(TERM) vt220`, which seems to have reduced the colours themselves, but these codes are still plentiful.  There's gotta be a way to get rid of them.  But if I set `TERM` to `dumb`, then `kvm` itself no longer works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `expect login:` instead of `expect "login: "`.

Comment: The thing is that `expect "login: "` actually works, just not every single time the script is run; and when the script fails, it doesn't always fail at the `login: ` stage, either.

Comment: According to your `expect -d` output `expect "login: "` does not work since the string is actually `login:\u001b` which does not match `"login: "` just as the last part of debug output says: `match glob pattern "login: "? no`.

Comment: Yes, during the provided run, obviously, it didn't match, as per the debug output.  However, on every other run, it does actually have a proper space, and does match successfully.  It seems that these spaces at the end of the lines sometime do show up, and sometimes do not, in both this and other cases (e.g., matching `# `, too, fails, but only sometimes).  Which is really confusing, and is the whole source of this question.

Comment: So the solution is `expect login:` instead of `expect "login: "`.

Comment: It wouldn't solve `expect "# "`, which, without the space, may match something completely unrelated.  There's no good reason this shouldn't be working properly, and downvoting the question simply because the tools (kvm+expect) don't work properly doesn't seem like a fair game.

Comment: I agree that `expect #` is not good practice. You can set your own special prompt after login.